# Mongodb gets slow when hosted

Tags: java, mongodb, digital-ocean

I am implementing a Desktop app using Java SE. I used Mongodb locally and every thing was extremely fast. However,  I decided to deploy the database online on the mongodb Atlas and i used their connection line which starts with mongodb:// from here the app got extremely slow due to connection. I tried to deploy it on Digital ocean droplet with the same connection string mongodb://ip_adress:port. It became a bit faster but not so much.

*Timing Local : 1-2 seconds

*Timing on Mongo atlas : 8-10 sec. (free tier shared cluster)

*Timing on Digital Ocean server : 7-8 sec.

**Note that :** the 8 sec is a JFrame that has some computations based on data from the database so it takes 8 sec to load when connection is online and nearly 0 time locally .

**Questions:**

*Is that a bad practice in implementation for app or database? which is not likely as it is extremely fast locally plus the database is still with simple testing data.

*Is that a bad server specs ? which does not seem as well to be the problem as no super heavy tasks on the server other than me testing and a website that is nearly never visited. ( digital ocean 5$ droplet)

**Logs**

- **Login**

```
Sep 22, 2019 8:24:21 PM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
INFO: Cluster created with settings {hosts=[ip_adress:27017], mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', maxWaitQueueSize=500}
Sep 22, 2019 8:24:21 PM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
INFO: Cluster description not yet available. Waiting for 30000 ms before timing out
Sep 22, 2019 8:24:23 PM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
INFO: Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:1, serverValue:84}] to ip_adress:27017
Sep 22, 2019 8:24:23 PM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
INFO: Monitor thread successfully connected to server with description ServerDescription{address=ip_adress:27017, type=STANDALONE, state=CONNECTED, ok=true, version=ServerVersion{versionList=[3, 6, 3]}, minWireVersion=0, maxWireVersion=6, maxDocumentSize=16777216, logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes=30, roundTripTimeNanos=425466400}
Sep 22, 2019 8:24:26 PM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
INFO: Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:2, serverValue:85}] to ip_adress:27017
Sep 22, 2019 8:24:27 PM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
INFO: Closed connection [connectionId{localValue:2, serverValue:85}] to ip_adress:27017 because the pool has been closed.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the connection time is pretty normal. you should make the call on a separate thread so it doesn't block your ui.

Comment: thanks for taking time to reply!! So you recommend using threading instead of moving the database locally to provide a smooth UI right ? I am not using threading that's why i am asking this..

Comment: However, what if I'm using retrieved data to provide some representations? like make a button red based on a status in the database? so then the UI is blocked until it finalize checking and retrieving

Comment: I also noticed that in the log the DB opens multiple connections while i am just initializing only one connection, I added the log in the question

Comment: you could show a little spinner. like what google does when it load gmail for example